# Timber/Twig - how to access a Wordpress Post Object inside a Repeater inside a Group

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

Here's my setup:

```
Twig Version: 1.34.4    
ACF Pro 5.8.8
```

---

I have the following ACF fields created, and I am trying to translate a working web page from standard PHP over to Twig.

**ACF Field Group > Group > Repeater > Post Object**

At the repeater level, I can access other standard fields fine, and I'm displaying these without a problem on the Twig template. My problem is how I access inside the Post Object so I can pull out the standard WP fields Title, Content etc.

I'm referencing the ACF cookbook at https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/, and thought the Relationship field might work, as such:

```
{% for item in Post(post.relationship_field) %} 
   {{ item.title }}
   {# Do something with item #}
{% endfor %}
```

However this doesn't output anything at all so I'm not sure it's working.

In my PHP page, I'm only passing in the standard post context like so:

```
$context['post'] = $post;
```

Do I have to add anything else to the PHP page in order to make this work, or should I be able to do this natively in the Twig template?

Comment: Can you `{{ dump(post) }}` and see anything?

Comment: When I run a full dump on the post it shows the Post ID that I need to access. That's obviously not the Post Object. The ACF settings are correct (set to return the Post Object), and on the previous non-twig PHP webpage I had to run a separate WP_Query to get the object.  What options do I have in Twig now then?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! I came across this answer which solved it for me [Issue with Post Object Timber/Twig WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805121/issue-with-post-object-timber-twig-wordpress). Though the Post ID was being returned in the dump, it seems I was trying to access it in an incorrect way.